# Scala - Use mathematical operations on AnyVal

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am writing generic mathematical operation functions that work on Spark RDDs of numeric values.

For multiplication, I have something that looks like this:

```
def mult(rdd1: RDD[AnyVal], rdd2: RDD[AnyVal]): RDD[AnyVal] = {
    rdd1.zip(rdd2).map(row => row._1 * row._2)
}
```

`*` is not a member of AnyVal, so this doesn't compile. Is there something I could do to make this work?

Comment: Well if you're really sure that you will be getting a numerical type and not maybe a string then you can explicitly cast it with `.asInstanceOf[NumericalTypeYouNeed]`. Needless to say this is not recommended as it will blow up at runtime if something else arrives and I would question why are `rdd1` and `rdd2` `AnyVal`s in the first place.

Comment: @AkosKrivachy I used AnyVal because the RDDs contain numeric values. Is there some better way to get this functionality?

Comment: Does `rdd1` and `rdd2` always have the same numeric type?

Comment: @CoreyWu Well use the explicit numeric type that you get from your source: `Int`, `Long`, `Double`, `Float`, `BigDecimal`, whatever. Your RDDs should be typed as soon as possible so that you can perform these operations easily. If you maybe provide more info on where `rdd1` and `rdd2` come from then we can help.

Comment: @m-z No, they can have differing types.

Comment: @AkosKrivachy rdd1 and rdd2 are RDDs that contain numeric values of one type. So outside of this function I create 2 RDDs: rdd1 contains values of ```Int``` or ```Long``` or ```Double```, etc and rdd2 contains values of possibly a different numeric type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using `Numeric` for numeric types?

this should work:

```
  def mult[X:Numeric](rdd1: RDD[X], rdd2: RDD[X]): RDD[X] = {
    import Numeric.Implicits._
    rdd1.zip(rdd2).map(row => row._1 * row._2)
  }
```

If you want to be able to multiply anything with anything, then you need to tell the compiler how to do it.

To do so, let's declare a trait that describes the functionality:

```
trait Multiplier[A, B, C] {
  def multiply(a: A, b: B): C
}
```

Now you can define a generic function multiply that lifts the multiplication to other types (I will use `Seq` you can use `RDD`):

```
def multiply[A,B,C](as:Seq[A],bs:Seq[B])(implicit multiplier: Multiplier[A,B,C]): Seq[C] =
  as zip bs map ( p => multiplier.multiply(p._1, p._2))
```

Now let's tell the compiler how to multiply an `Int` with a `String` (Scala can multiply a `String` with an `Int`, but not the other way around.) So let's define the multiplier:

```
implicit object IntStringMultipler extends Multiplier[Int, String, Seq[String]] {
  override def multiply(a: Int, b: String): Seq[String] = (1 to a) map (_ => b)
}
```

To make it more interesting, `2 * "x"` will be `Seq("x", "x")` not `"xx"` like Scala's own `"x" * 2`.

Now we can call: `multiply(Seq(2, 3), Seq("a", "b"))` to get `List(Vector("a", "a"), Vector("b", "b", "b"))`

Comment: Cool answer! Although I don't think this solves the underlying problem of having `AnyVal`s :)

Comment: Indeed, it does not. Also I have noted too late rdd1 and rdd2 can of different types. In any case, the compiler needs to know, how to multiply the items of the RDDs, so it will be necessary to use some types that have the multiplication defined. I will try tu update my answer with two types.